# How do I overcome IE8 getting "stuck" in SCORM 4th Edition Compliance Test SX-05?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, scorm, scorm2004

I am posting this in the off chance there is a SCORM expert out there that may have seen something similar.

Internet Explorer 8 gets "stuck" on step 14 of test case SX-05. Something doesn't trigger the continue. No amount of debugging and tracing reveals anything. It's as if the test case is "overwhelming" IE8's slow JavaScript engine. All other tests run fine in IE8. This one is quite complex, but there are others of similar complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be rather obscure. Our LMS was writing a loading page to the content iframe before loading the actual SCO.

```
window.frames.contentFrame.document.open();
window.frames.contentFrame.document.write(html);
window.frames.contentFrame.document.close();
```

I changed the loading page to a static HTML page and everything chugged along fine. Modifying the document that way screws up some window events on Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Install Chrome. No one can fix IE

Comment: The ADL test suites are IE only

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pausing the test before you get to SX-05, closing the browser and then resuming the test? That might help.

Are you sure it is an IE issue? We have successfully run the 4th Ed test suite many times without issue. If the test always stops at the exact same place, it seems unlikely that it is a resource issue. At what point does the execution stop?

Comment: Thanks @Mike. The same test works fine in Firefox. Putting it in the debugger breaks on all kinds of "non-errors" that seem to indicate the engine is getting overloaded. If I put in a bunch of alerts, the test completes successfully. Trace reveals that Terminate is somehow not triggered...

Comment: Are you using a code debugger, or do you have a listing of all SCORM calls you can access from your LMS?